What actions can I take at the institution level if my midterm grade was handed to me after the withdrawal date of the course?
I am currently taking a course which I have no grades including assignments, final project, and other milestones. This does not mean I did not do them, its just that they are not graded. I had an ungraded midterm grade which I just received today. The midterm grade is indicative that I will not be passing the class. The semester ends on December 19th, and I have no grades in other categories. As well I have a final project due on December 19th to present. Is the situation salvageable and how? Do I contact the Dean or the chair of the department regarding the situation the professor is the director of the PhD program.

You should contact your advisor and Dean of Students with questions of this nature. I would not escalate all the way to the dean of the college at this preliminary stage. At most the chair for now. There isn't much we can help with because we don't know what the institutional norms and policies are regarding these issues. Some universities are not very strict with this (like mine), others are.

I don’t understand the situation. It’s very unclear to me what is actually part of the course and what affects grading, and actually whether there is grading at all. Various parts of the question lean one way, other parts another way. FWIW, what I am reading into the question is basically that you expect to be able to withdraw from every course that you would fail so that you don’t fail officially. At least for the universities I know (Europe) that’s really not the point of grading, withdrawal and tracking failures. Failure is tracked for a purpose.

It's not at all clear from your account how you are actually graded in this class. If your midterm does not actually have any effect on your final grade, then I would say that weakens your case. @MisterMiyagi It is normal in the US that there is a cut-off date for withdrawing from classes, perhaps around the time of the first midterm exam, and that students who suspect they might fail the class will take advantage of this option.

What is an "ungraded midterm grade"? Sounds a bit like a colorless green idea.

@AdamPřenosil To be more precise, in the US schools I've been at, the undergrad drop deadline is about 4-6 weeks in, roughly the first midterm. The withdrawal deadline, where a "W" grade is entered on your transcript, varies from 4 weeks prior to just before finals. The graduate drop deadline is very late, either the last day of classes or even up to the administration of the final.

@user71659 Right. I assumed that the OP meant the former but given how far we are into the semester they probably meant the latter.

I would first take a pause and try not to panic. You're enrolled in this course, the semester isn't over yet, your focus should still be on performing well in the rest of the course; even if all that is left is a final exam, it's important.
Your next stop should be the course instructor. Talk to them about your concerns about the course. It's possible the grades will be curved in some way and that performance on the midterm was poor overall - your grade might not be as bad as you think it is. Talk to your instructor.
Whether there is some way for you to still drop the course is entirely up to your institution's policies, but I doubt that there is. The purpose of course drops is not to evade failing: if you fail a course, you fail. There may be alternatives to replace a grade on your transcript or for your GPA, such as re-taking the course later on.
I understand you're likely frustrated that none of your work in the course was graded until so late. Delayed grading really destroys the pedagogical usefulness of grades to be a signal of where you need to improve and what you might focus on.
If in fact your grade really is as bad as you are thinking initially, this should not have been your first hint that you are struggling in the course. If you're in graduate school, you have a lot of experience by now at how academic courses work. You're responsible for your work in a course, and if you're feeling lost or struggling with the material you should have been doing something about it earlier (like talking to the instructor) rather than waiting for a grade to come in and see what it looks like. It's possible that the cost of this lesson this time around is a failing grade; you certainly wouldn't be the first to learn this way, though it's normally a lesson that comes earlier on. Even if you feel like you've lost control of this one course, you'll have an opportunity to determine how you use this lesson for yourself in the future.

Excellent answer.
